# Flutter Todoey App problem onLongpress: longpressCallback

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

#### I have this one single problem in the task_title.dart page with the [onLongPress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlHQP.jpg): longPressCallback, [line 14] where it says that

(error: The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [todoey_flutter] lib/widgets/task_tile.dart:14)

**> please can anyone help me????**

[file:///Users/mdrubayat/Desktop/Image%206-12-21%20at%209.53%20PM.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1veE.jpg)

here is the code>>

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TaskTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isChecked;
  final String taskTitle;
  final Function checkboxCallback;
  final Function longPressCallback;

  TaskTile({required this.isChecked, required this.taskTitle, required this.checkboxCallback, required this.longPressCallback});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      onLongPress: longPressCallback,
      title: Text(
        taskTitle,
        style: TextStyle(
            decoration: isChecked ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null),
      ),
      trailing: Checkbox(
        activeColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        value: isChecked,
        onChanged: (newValue) {
          checkboxCallback(newValue);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code that throws the error please?

Comment: yeah sure i have given the code

Comment: Try adding () => before longPressCallback

Comment: I think the problem is not on longPressCallback but on checkboxCallback. What does that function look like? if newValue is boolean try to do something like final Function(bool) checkboxCallback;

Comment: Thank you so much @JaimeOrtiz your solution worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

The property onLongPress of ListTile required a Void Function.
At the moment, you are using a Function which could potentially not be of Void type.

You should define the argument longPressCallback as a void Function:

```
final void Function() longPressCallback;
```